# PHP/Symfony - how do I pass javascript variable to PHP script

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

Following is my code snippet.

```
function funcUrl(){

    var element = 10; 

    '<a href="<?=url_for('@someurl?id=' + element)?>"

}
```

--please see the above javascript function. I am passing the javascript variable element in the PHP script of href. Howver it gives me error beacuse of element variable. If I just harcode the value instead of passing javascript varibal it works just fine. Can someone help me how to pass the javascript varibale correctly in the above script so taht I can pass the value of the parameter dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass a variable in a GET you should encode it.  In PHP that is done with [`rawurlencode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php).  You can do the same thing in Javascript with [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

You will then need to decode the value in your PHP script with [`rawurldecode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rawurldecode.php).

Comment: Can you please provide a code snippet? Isn't there any way we can pass the javascript variable value in the script?

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
function funcUrl(){

    var element = 10; 

    '<a href="<?=url_for('@someurl?id='.'<script>'+element+'</script>')?>"></a>'

}
```